# Queued kernels slower than expected on AMD gpus only

Tags: opencl

I am performing a benchmark like show below

```
CHECK( context = clCreateContext(props, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &_err); );
CHECK( queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, 0, &_err); );
#define SYNC() clFinish(queue)
#define LAUNCH(glob, loc, kernel) OCL(clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2,\
                                                             NULL, glob, loc,\
                                                             0, NULL, NULL))

/* Build program, set arguments over here */


START;
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    LAUNCH(global, local, plus_kernel);
}
SYNC();
STOP;
printf("Time taken (plus) : %lf\n", uSec / iter);

START;
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    LAUNCH(global, local, minus_kernel);
}
SYNC();
STOP;
printf("Time taken (minus): %lf\n", uSec / iter);

START;
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
    LAUNCH(global, local, plus_kernel);
    LAUNCH(global, local, minus_kernel);
}
SYNC();
STOP;
printf("Time taken (both) : %lf\n", uSec / iter);
```

The results look weird:

```
Time taken (plus) : 31.450000
Time taken (minus): 28.120000
Time taken (both) : 2256.380000
```

`START`, and `STOP` are just macros that start and stop a timer.
Here are the relevant macros.

I am not sure why queuing up is the kernels is slowing them down (and only on AMD GPUs)!

**EDIT** I am using Radeon 7970

**EDIT** Both kernels are operating on independent memory. Also here is the system information.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10

fglrxinfo:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7900 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.2.11762 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Comment: Are the same memory objects used for both kernels, or are they different for each kernel?

Comment: @KLee1 Both of them are independent. I tried creating the queue in out of order mode, but that did not change anything either. Could it be a driver issue ?

Comment: what catalyst driver version are you using? Have you used AMD APP Profiler to check why queuing is taking so much time, is it because of the copying global/local memory from Host to GPU ?

Comment: How long does one iteration take?  In your timing average, you're making the assumption that all iterations take the same amount of time.  Does this assumption hold?

Comment: @KLee1 That was an interesting observation. The average time varies with the number of iterations. So either I am not timing it properly or I am not catching something that is happening under the hood. But the same code provides consistent results on NVIDIA GPUs though. So color me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer has to do with caching of data on newer GPUs (Specifically the Radeon 7970, which uses the [Graphics Compute Next (GCN)](http://www.amd.com/us/Documents/GCN_Architecture_whitepaper.pdf) architecture.

One of the advantages of this architecture is it's caching capabilities (somewhat close to CPU caching at this point).  If you perform calls like this:

```
PLUS
PLUS 
PLUS
....
```

Then the memory that is resident in the inner caches of the GPU.  On the other hand if you make calls like this:

```
PLUS
MINUS
PLUS 
MINUS
...
```

Where the two kernels have different memory objects associated with them, then the data is kicked out of the hardware devices on each CU, causing a need for them to be brought in from the very sluggish global memory.

Two easy ways to test if this is the case:

1. Run only Pluses with varying numbers of iterations.  As the number of iterations increases, the average time will go down because the cost of the first run (which brings the data in) is amortized.  Also, you should notice that all calls after the first should be relatively equal.
2. Make the Plus and Minus kernels run on the same memory objects.  If the reason for the slowdown is because of the caching of memory objects, then the overall run time should be the average of the individual running times of PLUS and MINUS (depending perhaps on experiment 1).

Let me know if you find out if this is actually the case!

Comment: That explains a lot. I did see behavior explained in (1). I do not have access to the AMD machine right now, but can report back in a couple of days. Sorry about not replying earlier.